# Help identifying font used on signage

Tags: font-identification

I need help identifying the font used on this sign. This is the clearest photo of it I have, and the shadows are throwing off all the font-matching tools I've tried.

[image]

I have tried Identifont, What the Font, Fontpring's Matcherator, Fontsquirrel's Matcherator, and have been manually digging through lists of fonts to try and eyeball a match. No dice. I've tried isolating the letters from the shadow in photoshop, but have had poor results.

I'm hoping someone might know it on sight? I feel like I saw it used a lot in the 90s (or maybe I'm thinking of Trajan), certainly I've seen that **A** used in logos before, like a movie production company or a non-profit... It's driving me insane! Any clues anyone has to help me investigate would be appreciated.

Comment: I also first thought Trajan Pro, then went an looked to realize I was wrong.  Maybe it's a custom variant or mixture of fonts.  I know I've done that a lot in the past myself--use characters from a few different fonts to make my own "custom" font

Comment: Identifont gave me [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9JFoI.png)......

Comment: @Cai HAHA! So close! :P

Comment: I'm intrigued so I traced the letters and tried what the font etc. No luck. It definitely looks familiar.

Comment: That A has to be customized. The R looks like a Garamond of some sort. The M, i, l and V also suggest a Garamond.

Comment: @bemdesign I was thinking one of the Garamonds, but I can't find any variants with a capital G that has that combo of tapered terminal at the top and spur at the bottom. I agree the A is probably custom, but I'm skeptical about the G. Probably something derivative of Garamond, at least. I'm going to keep digging, but GAH!

Comment: I have some similar advise which called Cinzel https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cinzel

Comment: @FerdiÇıldız That's pretty dang close!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like the base was the [Felix Titling](https://www.google.de/search?q=felix%20titling&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj-pDcvufOAhWCnBoKHTgqCVQQsAQIJg&biw=1904&bih=941) and then customized ('A' and 'R'). Just compare the 'G' and 'M'. Also if you scale the end of the swoosh of the 'R' a little bit down it matches the curve of the original perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when suggesting a font please make sure to include a screenshot of the font.   Some people do not like to click on links they're unfamiliar with and an answer should be able to live with relying on external references to illustrate what you're trying to say.

Comment: And like that I will magically reward you with my currency. . .

Comment: YES YES YES!!!! I knew I recognized it from college. We used Felix Titling on graduation invitations when I worked in the copy center on campus. YES! Thank you!!!